# Angularjs and Google Charts convert Date in JSON Date?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, google-visualization

i want build on server side (spring/java) a DataTable or DataArray that i can use for google charts. The Problem is the Date Format.
I have first build a Data Array and serialized it to json that looks like that:

{DataArray:[["Date","New York","Austin"],[100,200,300]]}

on the client side i can parse this DataArray to a DataTable this is no problem..

But if i want add a Date, Angular throws an error because the json string is then not well formated.

on the client side i can use this, this creates me from an array a DataTable:

> data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
>                       ['date','New York','Austin','San Francisco','Country','Popularity'],
>                       [new Date("8/6/1975"),2,3,15,'Germany',200],
>                       [new Date("8/6/1980"),5,6,19,'Brazil',400],
>                       [new Date("8/6/2000"),8,9,23,'United States',300],
>                       [new Date("8/6/2010"),11,12,35,'RU',700]
>                   ])

there i can use new Date() this worked but how can i create for example "new Date("8/6/1975")" on server side and send it to my client and then on client side it should create a Date Object.

Has someone an idear how i can do that ? Can i use the json date format ? If so, how can i create on server side a json date that looks on the client side like that "new Date("8/6/1975")" and creates me an Date object ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your dates as strings on the server-side, in this format:

```
'Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)'
```

where `month` is 0-indexed (so January is 0, not 1), and `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`, `second`, and `millisecond` are all optional (default is `1` for `day` and `0` for all others).

Your header for the date column also needs to specify that the column is a "date" type, otherwise the `arrayToDataTable` method will interpret it as a string.  Instead of using the string `'date'` in the header row, use an object:

```
{label: 'date', type: 'date'}
```